# Permute rows in data frame according to a specific pattern

Tags: r

My data frame looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3)) %>%
          mutate(val = paste0(grp, 1:3))

  grp val
1   a  a1
2   a  a2
3   a  a3
4   b  b1
5   b  b2
6   b  b3
7   c  c1
8   c  c2
9   c  c3
```

I want to permute the row order of `df` by `grp` such that every 3 consecutive rows must contain a, b and c in random order. Below are three examples of how the outputs should look like:

```
  grp val        grp val        grp val
1   a  a1      9   c  c3      7   c  c1
8   c  c2      2   a  a2      1   a  a1
4   b  b1      5   b  b2      6   b  b3
3   a  a3      4   b  b1      9   c  c3
9   c  c3      3   a  a3      3   a  a3
6   b  b3      7   c  c1      4   b  b1
7   c  c1      6   b  b3      5   b  b2
2   a  a2      8   c  c2      8   c  c2
5   b  b2      1   a  a1      2   a  a2
```

Ideally the solution should also work for similar data frames of the form:

```
df <- data.frame(grp = rep(letters[1:x], each = y)) %>%
          mutate(val = paste0(grp, 1:(x*y)))
# where x and y may be natural numbers
```

I tried to play around with the `group_by` and `sample_n` functions, without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dplyr approach:

```
df %>% 
  sample_frac(1) %>%                  # order randomly
  group_by(grp) %>%                   # group by "grp" column 
  group_by(row = row_number()) %>%    # group by 1:n in each "grp" group
  sample_frac(1)                      # sample all rows from these groups
```

Afterwards, you can extend the pipe with `%>% ungroup() %>% select(-row)` to remove the newly created grouping column.

---

The results of two sampling runs are as follows

```
replicate(2, sample_frac(df, 1) %>% group_by(grp) %>% 
             group_by(row = row_number()) %>%
             sample_frac(1), simplify = FALSE)
# [[1]]
# Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
# Groups: row [3]
# 
#     grp   val   row
#   <fctr> <chr> <int>
# 1      b    b1     1
# 2      c    c1     1
# 3      a    a2     1
# 4      a    a1     2
# 5      c    c2     2
# 6      b    b2     2
# 7      b    b3     3
# 8      c    c3     3
# 9      a    a3     3
# 
# [[2]]
# Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
# Groups: row [3]
# 
#     grp   val   row
#   <fctr> <chr> <int>
# 1      c    c3     1
# 2      a    a3     1
# 3      b    b3     1
# 4      a    a1     2
# 5      b    b2     2
# 6      c    c1     2
# 7      c    c2     3
# 8      a    a2     3
# 9      b    b1     3
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that uses `replicate`, `sample`, `rep`, and `t`. This assumes that there are the same number of groups as there are units within a group.

```
permuter <- function(n) c(t(replicate(n, sample(n))) + (rep(seq_len(n)-1) * n))
```

This uses `replicate` to sample the number of elements in each group, effectively ordering the selection of within-group elements. The matrix output is added to a sequence that adjusts for the number of groups. The matrix resulting from this is transposed to get between group ordering and then converted into a vector that lists the new positions of the rows.

```
permuter(3)
[1] 1 5 7 2 6 9 3 4 8
```

To reorder, just feed the result to `[`.

```
df[permuter(3), ]
  grp val
1   a  a1
5   b  b2
7   c  c1
2   a  a2
6   b  b3
9   c  c3
3   a  a3
4   b  b1
8   c  c2
```

Note that I used `set.seed(1234)` to reproduce the same output of the function in both instances.

---

*more flexible permutation*

In the instance of having different numbers of groups versus within group size (say 3 groups, each with 4 units), the following, more flexible function would work.

```
permuterFlex <- function(numG, wSize) {
  c(t(replicate(numG, sample(wSize)) + rep(seq_len(numG)-1, each=wSize) * (wSize)))
}
```

Here, numG is the number of groups and wSize is the number of units within a group. To see this replicates the above result.

```
set.seed(1234)
permuterFlex(3, 3)
[1] 1 5 7 2 6 9 3 4 8
```